# Linq to return only selected columns from table

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to return only some columns from a LINQ query. How do I do that?
Here is the asp.net:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="RequestorDataEntitySource" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="name=RequestDataEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="RequestDataEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="requests"
        OnQueryCreated="Requestor_QueryCreated" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="RequestorGridView" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="RequestorDataEntitySource">
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void Requestor_QueryCreated(object sender, QueryCreatedEventArgs e)
    {

        var currentRequestor = e.Query.Cast<requests>();
        e.Query = (from rq in currentRequestor
                   where rq.lname == "Somebody"
                   select rq);
    }
```

This fills up the grid with all 20 columns, but can I choose just a few specific columns (fname, lname, email)? I've seen quite a few posts here on this subject, but I couldn't get those examples to work for me. If I try to change the select to something like:

```
   select new { rq.fname, rq.lname });
```

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: QueryCreated event returned a query of type 'ObjectQuery`1' when type 'ObjectQuery`1' is required.

I'm missing something, please enlighten.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the **Select** property is what you need:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="RequestorDataEntitySource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=RequestDataEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="RequestDataEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="requests"
    Select="it.fname, it.lname"
    OnQueryCreated="Requestor_QueryCreated" >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you initially select in the entitydatasource should be the same as in the on-query created.